# How do I get the Title column of my SharePoint Online doc library to show the title of PDF documents?

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, pdf

I have a simple document library on my department's SharePoint Online site. I've uploaded a mix of Word documents and PDF documents to it.

I want to show the title of each document.

I've worked out how to make a title column appear (I'm a SharePoint novice so that in itself was an achievement). SharePoint automatically fills in the title column for the Word documents with the title I entered in the title metadata box in Word's save dialog.

However SharePoint doesn't seem to do the same for the PDF files. I am pretty sure the title metadata is in the PDF file - I filled in that field when I did the `Save As PDF` and I also verified the title field was there using the Evermap AutoMetadata metadata reader utility - but SharePoint doesn't seem to pick up on it.

Why? Is there something I can do to fix this? In your replies, please remember that I'm a SharePoint novice and not quick on the uptake when it comes to software.

I'm using SharePoint Online

Comment: hi you have got my interest as I work with both SharePoint on premise office 365. I haven't noticed this before but will try uploading a pdf to both envs and report back. ..Normally the title is optional but the name property is updated when the file is uploaded to the library. I will start with looking at your views.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone reading this and asking the same question I am of just displaying the title column in the first place.

1. Go to your Library Settings
2. Scroll Down to your views
3. Should have one named All Documents (Or the view you want). Click it or the view you want the Title Column to appear in.
4. Then just enable the Title Column (mine was at the bottom) and move it to the position where you want it displayed

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint supports property promotion (i.e. title from Word file is copied to the SharePoint column title) for Office files.

For pdf files this is not possible. You will need to add the title manually or use 3rd party tools that allow mapping of document properties (e.g. title in pdf, GPS location in jpg file, ...) to SharePoint columns.

There are also tools emerging that can extract properties from SharePoint files and capture the values into SharePoint columns (e.g. order ID from pdf invoice, sent date from emails, GPS coordinates from photo, ...).